# Odata serialization error for SingleResult.Create on an empty IQueryable

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, odata, iqueryable

I'm using OData v4 and trying to get a really simple controller working:

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : ODataController
{
readonly MasterDataEntities db = new MasterDataEntities();

[EnableQuery(PageSize = MaxPageSize)]
public IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
    return db.Products;
}

[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<Product> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(db.Products.Where(p => p.Code == key));
}
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
builder.EntityType<Product>().HasKey(p => p.Code);
config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
```

When I make a call to servicelocation/Product('abc')

If abc is a valid code, I get a nicely JSON serialized Product object back

If abc is an invalid code I get the following error:

'SingleResult`1' cannot be serialized using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter.

at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.GetSerializer(Type type, Object value, IEdmModel model, ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)

I've spent 2 days looking for a solution now but it seems nobody else gets this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please see this workaround [here](https://gist.github.com/andygjp/82106facbb0c43f55dc8)

> A workaround that will recognise when a SingleResult type does not contain any results and replace it with a 404 instead of throwing a SerializationException.

Comment: Absolute ledgend! Should have asked this yesterday haha! Thanks a million

Comment: I've had issues with this workaround. If using a $batch request where one of the SingleResults is empty, it will return 404 for the entire $batch instead of just that part.

Comment: Can someone please explain the steps on how to use the workaround?. I am new to .NET would be helpful