# OData cannot serialize a null resource

Tags: c#, .net, odata

When the arguments given in an OData query does not find a result - how will you be handling the returned null value. I get this exception if it happends that there are no retult or I simply return null without ever searching.

**Error: Cannot serialize a null 'Resource'**

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Cannot serialize
> a null 'Resource'.    at
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object
> graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer,
> ODataSerializerContext writeContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSerializer.WriteObject(Object
> graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter,
> ODataSerializerContext writeContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatterHelper.WriteToStream(Type
> type, Object value, IEdmModel model, ODataVersion version, Uri
> baseAddress, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, IWebApiUrlHelper
> internaUrlHelper, IWebApi

I would expect it to return an empty result and a 204 code - but it returns an empty result with a 200 code and throws the exception in the console.

Here is some sample code from the controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("Topic/{id}")]
public TopicDto? GetTopic(string id)
{
    return _dbTableContext.Topic.Find(id);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want a 204 status code returned?

Comment: @prd The 204 means request ok, but no content found. I can live with the 200 and empty result, but I need to get rid of the exception in the console.

Comment: No, 204 just means "no content" which would be an appropriate response code for a successful object creation via POST, in this case 404 is correct as per REST.

Comment: Got it. Any thoughts about the exception handling?

Comment: Hopefully the solution on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573755/odata-serialization-error-for-singleresult-create-on-an-empty-iqueryable/35573947) post may help you.

Comment: "One of the property of your TopicDto class is a list and is set to null, hence it's not able to be serialized."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning an `IActionResult` instead of a nullable `TopicDto` from your controller methods, as this leaves you with more flexibility regarding HTTP responses.

> The same principle applies to ASP.NET but with `IHttpActionResult` as the return type.

***TopicsController.cs***

```cs
[ODataRoutePrefix("topics")]
public class TopicsController : ODataController
{
    private static readonly TopicViewModel[] _topics = new TopicViewModel[]
    {
        new TopicViewModel { Id = 1, Title = "Topic A"},
        new TopicViewModel { Id = 2, Title = "Topic B"},
        new TopicViewModel { Id = 3, Title = "Topic C"}
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var topic = _topics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (topic == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(topic);
    }
}
```

***API Test using cURL***

```
curl -i "https://localhost:44391/odata/topics(1)"
HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
odata-version: 4.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Fri, 21 Aug 2020 09:28:42 GMT

{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44391/odata/$metadata#Topics/$entity","Id":1,"Title":"Topic A"}
```

```
curl -i "https://localhost:44391/odata/topics(0)"
HTTP/2 404
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Fri, 21 Aug 2020 09:28:54 GMT
```

Comment: If you still want to stick with TopicDto - then simply handle the null on your list property (of the TopicDto class)

Answer (score 0):

In my case - I had an object where one of it's property was a List<> and it was set to null.
When I returned this object back - from response to my Serializer - it failed with the above exception.

Simply initializing the property to a new List<> would solve your problem.